# Как подсчитать сумму в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Как подсчитать сумму cmon в массивах? Надо получить сумму массива red и black.

```
let arr=[
    {id: 44, bet: 2, cmon: 3, lroom: 1000},
    {id: 45, bet: 1, cmon: 20, lroom: 1000},
    {id: 432, bet: 2, cmon: 4, lroom: 1000},
    {id: 45, bet: 1, cmon: 30, lroom: 1000}
    ];
const red = arr.filter(item => item.bet !== 1),black = arr.filter(item => item.bet !== 2); 
console.log(red) //Сумма red  cmon 
console.log(black) //Сумма black  cmon
```

Comment: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce): `array.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator += current.cmon, 0)`

Comment: Что такое `red` и `black`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Отфильтрованные массивы

Comment: @Bald Спасибо понял

Answer (score 5, accepted):

без разделения на массивы как-то так

```js
let arr=[
    {id: 44,  bet: 2, cmon: 3,  lroom: 1000},
    {id: 45,  bet: 1, cmon: 20, lroom: 1000},
    {id: 432, bet: 2, cmon: 4,  lroom: 1000},
    {id: 45,  bet: 1, cmon: 30, lroom: 1000}
  ];
    
var res = arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
              let key =  v.bet == 1 ? 'red' : 'black';
              acc[key] += v.cmon;
              return acc;
           }, { red: 0, black: 0 } )    ;
           
console.log(res);
```

либо  на новый манер так

```js
let arr=[
    {id: 44,  bet: 2, cmon: 3,  lroom: 1000},
    {id: 45,  bet: 1, cmon: 20, lroom: 1000},
    {id: 432, bet: 2, cmon: 4,  lroom: 1000},
    {id: 45,  bet: 1, cmon: 30, lroom: 1000}
  ];
    
    
var {1:red, 2:black} = arr.reduce((acc, v) => (acc[v.bet] += v.cmon, acc), { 1: 0, 2:0 } );
           
console.log(red, black);
```